# Derivative of $x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}$?

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation, tetration

The infinite tetration is defined as
$$f(x)=x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}$$

This function is defined for $e^{-e} \leq x \leq e^{e-1}$.

(Wikipedia image)

[image: Infinite Tetration]

Can one determine the derivative of this function?

Comment: If you're talking about the infinite power tower, then you shouldn't be ending the tower with an $x$.

Comment: @J.M. Very true.  Edited.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/868528/3936

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Letting $h(x)$ be your infinite power tower, one can solve the functional equation $h(x)=x^{h(x)}$ in terms of the Lambert function $W(x)$, the inverse function of $x\exp\,x$. More specifically, we have

$$h(x)=\exp(-W(-\log\,x))$$

One can then apply the chain rule as usual. The formula

$$W^\prime(x)=\frac{\exp(-W(x))}{1+W(x)}$$

is easily derived through implicit differentiation of the relationship $W(x)\exp(W(x))=x$.

We thus have

$$h^\prime(x)=\frac{\exp(-2 W(-\log\,x))}{x (1+W(-\log\,x))}=\frac{h(x)^2}{x(1-h(x)\log\,x)}$$

---

As lhf says, the functional equation for $h(x)$ can be differentiated implicitly, without needing to take the Lambert route:

$$\begin{align*}
h^\prime(x)&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}x^{h(x)}\\
h^\prime(x)&=x^{h(x)}\left(\frac{h(x)}{x}+h^\prime(x)\log\,x\right)\\
h^\prime(x)&=\frac{h(x)^2}{x}+h(x)h^\prime(x)\log\,x\\
h^\prime(x)-h(x)h^\prime(x)\log\,x&=\frac{h(x)^2}{x}\\
h^\prime(x)&=\frac{h(x)^2}{x(1-h(x)\log\,x)}\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: There is no need to bring $W$ into this. You can just differentiate $h(x)=x^{h(x)}$ and solve for $h'$.

Comment: @lhf: huh, I really was getting lazy there. Thanks for the note; I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

its given that $y=f(x)=x^{x^{x^{x^\cdots}}}$
 I can write this function as,

$$y=x^{y}$$

Taking $log_e$ on both sides, we have,

$$\log y=y\log x$$

Now, differentiate w.r.to $x$ on both sides,

$$\frac 1 y y'=\frac y x + y'\log x $$

$$ \left(\frac 1 y-\log x\right)y'=\frac y x$$
$$y'=\frac {y^2}{x(1-x\log x)}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac {x^{x^{x^{x^\cdots}}}}{x(1-x\log x)}$$