# How to differentiate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}_{n\text{ times}}$?

Tags: limits, derivatives, convergence-divergence, tetration

Let $$f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}_{n\text{ times}}$$
Is it possible to find $f'(x)$. If yes, please show all steps.

Comment: What is the domain of your function?

Comment: A recurrence is easy. Writing out the "unwound form" in LaTex, not so much.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html see the great section on the infinite tower, halfway down the page

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/138498/27624

Answer (score 13):

$\textbf{hint:}$
$$f(x) = x^{f(x)}$$
Then proceed

Comment: Simply brilliant.

Comment: I tried this. I've got f(x) in terms of Lambert W function, but I don't know W'(x).

Comment: Just take the derivative of both sides and solve for $f'(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$, @Mathematician171

Comment: This assumes that the limit exists and is differentiable, which isn't obvious at all. In fact for x>1 it obviously doesn't. Without specifying the domain an equally valid answer is $f'$ doesn't exist, or even $f$ doesn't exist for that matter.

Comment: @conifold you are absolutely correct. If in fact the domain does not permit the approach above then I hold my hands up and take it down. But I am afraid that's a question for the original poster :).

Comment: also $$\frac{{\rm d}W}{{\rm d}z}=\frac{W(z)}{z(1 + W(z))}\quad\text{for }z\not\in\{0,-1/e\}$$ if it's useful

Comment: @conifold: Without specifying a domain, the domain is whereever $f$ has a defined value. This appears to be the interval (0,1]. It looks like $f'$ is defined on (0,1).

Comment: Make that the interval $[e^{-e}, e^{1/e}] = [0.0659, 1.4446]$ (after reading the Wolfram article).

Comment: @IlikeSerena surprised that $e^{1/e}>1$

Comment: @JohnFernley: Yep. I am surprised as well. Still trying to make sense of that. But trying it out in [W|A](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5Bx%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2C1.5%7D%5D&x=0&y=0) confirms it.

Comment: @ilikeserena thank you for providing the domain. You can edit my "hint" accordingly ;) if you want. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This function is known as infinite tetration. The sequence is undefined for $x\leq 0$ except at some rational points, so there is no point talking about the derivative there. Ditto for large $x$, where the sequence diverges to $\infty$.

Rather surprisingly for $x>0$ the limit only exists for $x\in[e^{-e},e^{1/e}]$ as shown by Euler, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights.) and [here](https://orion.math.iastate.edu/rymartin/ISU492/Student%20files/IteratedExponentials_WangZhang.pdf). On that interval $f(x)$ is the inverse function to $x^{1/x}$. This implies differentiability there, and that's where formal games with implicit differentiation actually work. At first glance it seems strange that the sequence converges even for some values $x>1$ since then $x^x>x$ and it is monotone increasing. However, as long as the value of $x$ is close enough to $1$ this is similar to $(1+\frac1n)^n$ that monotone increases but converges to $e$. The threshold value  $e^{1/e}$ is the maximum of $x^{1/x}$, there is nothing to be inverse to for larger values.

Comment: It appears the upper limit is $e^{1/e} > 1$. I don't quite understand it though.

Comment: I personally think this is a better answer than mine when I look at the overall picture of the problem. +1

Comment: @Chinny84: Oh, your hint is still quite valid. It appears there is just more to it.

Answer (score 3):

WLOG, let $y = f(x)$. You know that $$y =x^y$$
So
$$\ln(y) =y\ln(x)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}*\frac{1}{y} = \frac{dy}{dx}*\ln(x) + \frac{y}{x}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y^2}{x-xy\ln(x)}$$